# Returns objects asyn with Format-Table and a specific layout

Tags: powershell

I want to return an object with a specific layout, each object should be displayed when returned.

If you run this code in PowerShell (not ISE) you see the result not until the function ends.

```
function Main
{
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt 10; $i++)
    { 
        [pscustomobject]@{Index=$i; TimeStamp=(Get-Date)}
        Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

Main | Format-Table @{Label="Index"; Expression={$_.Index};Width=10},
                    @{Label="TimeStamp"; Expression={$_.TimeStamp};Width=20}
```

This works, but I want to a specific layout.

```
function Main
{
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt 10; $i++)
    { 
        [pscustomobject]@{Index=$i; TimeStamp=(Get-Date)}
        Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

Main
```

And why is this behavior different if you execute this script in the ISE?

Comment: It works well in versions 3,4 and 5 on windows 10.

Comment: @Jower You get a return value every second and not all at the end? Here I have Windows 7 with PSReadline.

Comment: Yes that is correct! I have tried using powershell -version 3.0 and powershell -version 4.0 as well as the standard 5.0. I also tried powershell -version 2.0 but there i got no output whatsoever.

Comment: Code works for me in both PowerShell console and ISE (PowerShell v4 on Windows 7). You don't get output in PowerShell v2, because that version doesn't support `[pscustomobject]@{...}`, so you're not getting objects with the properties `Index` and `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

This line in my powershell profile was responsible for this behavior.

```
# The following function automatically adds -AutoSize for when I use Format-Wide or Format-Table
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Format-[wt]*:Autosize'] = $True
```